# How can i adjust the leverage with Bianance API

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I want to create a python script which trades on binance futures and i was wondering how i can set a leverage for a order. I search on google but didnt found anything abt it.

```
client.futures_create_order(symbol='VETUSDT', side='BUY', type='MARKET',  quantity = 1000)
```

Answer (score 5):

Leverage can not be sent with the order. You must first change the leverage and then send the order.
See: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#change-initial-leverage-trade

```
request_client = RequestClient(api_key=g_api_key, secret_key=g_secret_key)
result = request_client.change_initial_leverage(symbol="BTCUSDT", leverage=10)
```

from : https://github.com/Binance-docs/Binance_Futures_python/blob/master/example/trade/change_initial_leverage.py

Comment: Gives me this error: AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'change_initial_leverage'

Answer (score 1):

To change leverage with python-binance library you should use *futures_change_leverage()* method. Code example:

```
new_lvrg = 10

client = Client(your_api_key, your_api_secret)
client.futures_change_leverage(leverage=new_lvrg)
```

Comment: this worked for me: client.futures_change_leverage(symbol="BTCUSDT", leverage=10)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with the order. You have to do it separately:

```
new_lvrg = 10
symbol = 'BTCUSDT'

client = Client(your_api_key, your_api_secret)
client.futures_change_leverage(leverage=new_lvrg, symbol=symbol)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're all wrong.
Leverage should be in str (string).

```
new_lvrg = '10'
symb = 'BTCUSDT'

client = Client(your_api_key, your_api_secret)
client.futures_change_leverage(leverage=new_lvrg, symb=symbol)
```